# Crossvalidation in R and plots on cv doesn´t work

Tags: r, nan, feature-selection

I used the `cars` dataset with categorical and numerical data. I am to predict the price and want to perform cross validation (CV) to pick the best model. I created dummy variables for the categorical variables.

When I perform a subset selection and predict with CV it doesn't work.

I get strange NaN´s and the following error message:

```
> mean.cv.errors <- colMeans(cv.errors, na.rm = TRUE)
> print(mean.cv.errors)
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 
> par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
> plot(mean.cv.errors, type = "b", ylim = c(min(mean.cv.errors, na.rm = TRUE), max(mean.cv.errors, na.rm = TRUE)))
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(mean.cv.errors, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(mean.cv.errors, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

It also doesn't work when i do:

```
    mean.cv.errors <- colMeans(cv.errors, na.rm = TRUE)
print(mean.cv.errors)

par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
plot(mean.cv.errors, type = "b", ylim = c(min(mean.cv.errors, na.rm = TRUE), max(mean.cv.errors, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

I need to do CV on my subset, backward and forward selection as well as lasso. The lasso also gives an error:

This is my code:

```
# Factors -----------------------------------------------------------------

# Konvertera kategoriska variabler till faktorer
cars_train$Bränsle <- as.factor(cars_train$Bränsle)
cars_train$Växellåda <- as.factor(cars_train$Växellåda)
cars_train$Biltyp <- as.factor(cars_train$Biltyp)
cars_train$Drivning <- as.factor(cars_train$Drivning)


# Model-all -----------------------------------------------------------

model_all <- lm(Pris ~., cars_train)
summary(model_all)

# Räkna antalet NA-värden i varje kolumn
na_counts <- colSums(is.na(cars_train_all))

# Visa antalet NA-värden för varje kolumn
print(na_counts)

# Transmission not relevant dropping it
#cars_train <- subset(cars_train, select = -Växellåda)
#str(cars_train)

#  8 variabler
# 7 ska predikteras på Pris
# 1 är target Pris


# Backward selection ------------------------------------------------------

# Backward
model_back <- step(model_all, direction = "backward", trace = 0)
summary(model_back)

# Best subset modell 
regfit.full <- regsubsets(Pris ~ ., data = scaled_train_df, nvmax=10)
reg.summary <- summary(regfit.full)
reg.summary

names(reg.summary)
reg.summary$rsq

par(mfrow= c (1, 2))
plot(reg.summary$rss, xlab="Antal variabler", ylab="RSS", type="l")

plot(reg.summary$adjr2, xlab="Antal variabler", ylab="Adjusted Rsq", type="l")

which.max(reg.summary$adjr2)
points(10, reg.summary$adjr2[10], col="red", cex=2, pch=20)

par(mfrow= c (2, 2))
plot(regfit.full, scale="r2")
plot(regfit.full, scale="adjr2")
plot(regfit.full, scale="Cp")
plot(regfit.full, scale="bic")

par(mfrow= c (1,1))

coef(regfit.full, 5)

# Forward selection -------------------------------------------------------
# Forward selection model
regfit.fwd <- regsubsets(Pris ~ ., data = scaled_train_df, nvmax=10, method = "forward")
summary(regfit.fwd)

# Backward selection model
regfit.bwd <- regsubsets(Pris ~ ., data = scaled_train_df, nvmax=10, method = "backward")
summary(regfit.bwd)

# Sub, fwd, bwd
summary(regfit.full)
summary(regfit.fwd)
summary(regfit.bwd)

# Byt ut siffra vid behov
coef(regfit.full, 10)
coef(regfit.full, 10)
coef(regfit.full, 10)

# De olika modellerna väljer samma variabler. 
# Växelllåda verkar inte vara så viktig i de flesta modeller-
# Miltal, Modellår, Hästkrafter och Biltyper(främst Biltyp SUV) är viktiga i de flesta modeller

predict.regsubsets <- function(object, newdata, id, ...) {
  form <- as.formula (object$call[[2]])
  mat <- model.matrix (form, newdata)
  coefi <- coef (object, id = id)
  xvars <- names (coefi)
  mat[, xvars] %*% coefi
}

k <- 10
set.seed(42)
folds <- sample(1:k, nrow(scaled_train_df), replace = TRUE)
cv.errors <- matrix(NA, k, 10, dimnames = list(NULL, paste(1:10)))

for (j in 1:k) {
  best.fit <- regsubsets(Pris ~ ., data = scaled_train_df[folds != j, ], nvmax = 10)
  for (i in 1:10) {
    if (sum(best.fit$which[i, ]) > 0) {
      pred <- predict(best.fit, scaled_train_df[folds == j, ], id = i)
      
      # Invertera skalan på förutsägelserna och de faktiska värdena
      pred <- pred
      actual <- scaled_train_df$Pris[folds == j]
      
      cv.errors[j, i] <- mean((actual - pred)^2, na.rm = TRUE)
    }
  }
}

# Here comes the error!!!
mean.cv.errors <- colMeans(cv.errors, na.rm = TRUE)
print(mean.cv.errors)

 # Lasso model
> lasso.mod <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, lambda = grid)
> set.seed(42)
> cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1)
> plot(cv.out)
> bestlam <- cv.out$lambda.min
> # Prediction
> x_test <- model.matrix(Pris ~ ., data = scaled_test_df)
> lasso.pred <- predict(lasso.mod, newx = x_test, s = bestlam)
Error in predict.glmnet(lasso.mod, newx = x_test, s = bestlam) : 
  The number of variables in newx must be 10
> lasso.pred <- predict(lasso.mod, newx = x_test, s = bestlam)
Error in predict.glmnet(lasso.mod, newx = x_test, s = bestlam) : 
  The number of variables in newx must be 10
> # reset the scaling
> pred <- lasso.pred * pris_scale_factor + pris_scale
Error: object 'lasso.pred' not found
> actual <- scaled_test_df$Pris * pris_scale_factor + pris_scale
> # mean error
> mean_error <- mean((actual - pred)^2)>
```

I get this output:

```
 # Prediktion med lasso modell
> x_test <- model.matrix(Pris ~ ., data = scaled_test_df)
> lasso.pred <- predict(lasso.mod, newx = x_test, s = bestlam)
Error in predict.glmnet(lasso.mod, newx = x_test, s = bestlam) : 
  The number of variables in newx must be 10
> # Återställ skalan på förutsägelserna och de faktiska värdena
> pred <- lasso.pred * pris_scale_factor + pris_scale
Error: object 'lasso.pred' not found
> actual <- scaled_test_df$Pris * pris_scale_factor + pris_scale
> # Beräkna medelfelet
> mean_error <- mean((actual - pred)^2)
> print(mean_error)
[1] NaN
> # Plotta lasso modellen
> plot(lasso.mod)
Warning message:
In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
```

I have tried to scale numerical and categorical variables separately, to not scale Price (the target variable), and re-running the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

I can not provide any specific example for the question due to lack of dataset. But did you try `gamlr` package that integrate lasso and cross-validation.
The code will be like:

```
set.seed(0)
Matrix <- model.matrix(df$pris ~ ., data = df)[ , -1]
#If df$pris is a binary variable, use logit model. Otherwise do not.
#In this case df$pris is a numerical data.
cv.matrix1 <- cv.gamlr(Matrix, df$pris, nfold = "The fold you would like to use")

#Create regularization path
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(cv.matrix1$gamlr, main = "Lasso Regularization path")
plot(cv.matrix1, main = "Error against Lambda")
dim(Matrix)

#check non-zero coefficient in optimized model.
non_zero_coefs <- coef(cv.matrix1, select = "min")[which(coef(cv.matrix1, select = "min") != 0), ]
length(non_zero_coefs)
non_zero_coefs
sort(non_zero_coefs, decreasing = TRUE)
```

I'm also new to this, so I'm not sure this will definetly work. If you don't mind to provide orginal dataset, I would like to check if there is any thing wrong with the dataset itself.

Please let me if you have any further questions!